# What's the statistical way to rainbow table a web service?

Tags: distributions, power-law

Rainbow tabling a web service is getting a whole bunch of pages by guessing their IDs:

```
/item?ID=1
/item?ID=2
...
/item?ID=n
```

Ideally, I want to intelligently detect the max ID and set `n` to that. Is there a statistical approach here?

I was imagining like a "comb" where I check a radius of IDs around an exponentially increasing value:

```
9,10,11
99,100,101
999,1000,1001
9999,10000,10001
```

or maybe the exponentiation is dangerous, so just step by a constant:

```
999,1000,1001
1999,2000,2001
2999,3000,3001
```

E.g. if none of `2999,3000,3001` are valid IDs, then I set `n` to `3000`.

Should I be using some crazy distribution or formula with *e*?

*Note:* when DB admins want to make their IDs "unguessable," they often just choose a big number to start them at - say 100000, so item 1 is 100001, item 2 = 100002, etc.

*Note:* the brute force approach is just to set n to `2147483647` (the max value of MySQL's `INTEGER` type) or a smaller value if you know roughly how many objects there are in the database, and go one-by-one.